# How to map setUserInfo value to Subscriber record for Einstein Recommendations

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations, actions-and-recommendations

I understand it's possible (even desired) to pass something other than an email address (hashed) through the `email` parameter for the Einstein Collect Code, for `setUserInfo`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
   _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);     
   _etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "INSERT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUE_ID"}]);     
   _etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);    
</script>
```

Two questions:

1. Where does the resulting data get written to? Is it IGO_PROFILES?
2. If I pass through an identifier other than `SubscriberKey` (for example our site member ID, which also exists in our Contact_Salesforce synchronised data extension), how do I create the necessary mapping to ensure the right information is in the IGO_PROFILES data extension (particularly when Salesforce Contact ID is the Subscriber Key)? What needs to be in the user id and email fields?

Would really appreciate any information from anyone who has done this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data is recorded in the Einstein Apps in Reporting >> Contacts. When you see email think profileID. The value you pass in the setuserinfo creates the profiled with that value.

If you enable the DE integration it will write these values to igo_profiles in the email field, these DE are not used by the system and just to surface information to the account, you will see a delay in records being written here.

You can then use a query to match these to subscriberkey if you have the matching values and are not using subscriberkey in the setuserinfo call.

Whatever value you provide in the setuserinfo tag would just need to be included at the end of the email rec, for example:

`https://MID.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/HASHLOGICID/l/1/%%emailaddr%%`

If you are passing emailaddress in set userinfo you would just need to change `%%emailaddr%%` to `%%FIELDNAMEFROMDE%%`

`https://MID.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/HASHLOGICID/l/1/%%FIELDNAMEFROMDE%%`

AS far as Data Designer and how these DE are linked, if you are not using these in a JB Entry Filter or decision split they can simply be ignored. If you use case requires you to leverage these DE in one of the mentioned you would need to use emailaddress in the setuserinfo call

Comment: Thanks v much. I had watched Eliot Harper's fantastic webinar on Einstein (https://youtu.be/rOqLhEiediI?t=2271) and noted that the email address was needed for email recommendations (and looking at the data relationships for the IGO data extensions, I can see why).

Are you saying that I can pass any value but just need to relate this value to my member dataset with SQL (easily done)? I'm just struggling to see how I get to the point where I can insert the HTML recommendations snippet in an email and have it serve what my members should see.

Comment: Updated my answer